# Show only differences between two rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

Having a (MySQL) audit table containing rows that are similar, is it possible to view only those columns that have different values?

For example, a table containing four columns where column `key` is primary key, and column `id` is the identifier to match rows:

```
key   id   col1  col2
1     123     B     C
2     123     A     C
3     456     B     C
4     789     B     A
5     789     B     B
6     987     A     C
```

In the example above I need the query to return only row 1, 2, 4, and 5 as they have matching id, and differing values in col1 and col2, ie B,A and B,A.

```
key  id   col1   col2
1    123  B
2    123  A
4    789         A
5    789         B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it might not be very efficient solution, but gives what you want. HERE try this:

```
SELECT A.ID, (CASE A.col1 WHEN B.col1 THEN NULL ELSE B.col1 END), (CASE A.col2 WHEN B.col2 THEN NULL ELSE B.col2 END) FROM tblName A
FULL OUTER JOIN tblName B
ON
A.ID=B.ID
WHERE
(A.col1=B.col1 AND A.Col2<>B.Col2)
OR
(A.col2<>B.col2 AND A.Col1=B.Col1)
```

INNER JOIN should give same result

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit contrived, in the sense that adding more rows will give very different results - but anyway...

```
SELECT x.my_key
     , x.id
     , IF(y.col1=x.col1,'',x.col1) col1
     , IF(y.col2=x.col2,'',x.col2) col2 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.my_key <> x.my_key 
 WHERE (y.col1 <> x.col1 OR y.col2 <> x.col2) 
 ORDER 
    BY my_key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all responses which guided me.
Using your suggestions I made the sql like this:

```
SELECT
    T1.KEY,
    T1.ID,
    CASE T2.COL1_DISTINCT_VALUES WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE T1.COL1 END AS COL1,
    CASE T2.COL2_DISTINCT_VALUES WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE T1.COL2 END AS COL2
FROM
    TAB1 T1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        COUNT(DISTINCT COL1) AS COL1_DISTINCT_VALUES,
        COUNT(DISTINCT COL2) AS COL2_DISTINCT_VALUES
    FROM
        TAB1
    GROUP BY
        ID
) T2
ON T1.ID=T2.ID
WHERE
    T2.COL1_DISTINCT_VALUES > 1
OR  T2.COL2_DISTINCT_VALUES > 1
ORDER BY
   KEY,ID;
```